# Algoritmo de permutação simples

Tags: c#, .net, algoritmo

Estou tentando criar uma algoritmo de permutação simples onde você passa um numero qualquer por exemplo 123 e ele deve retornar o maior numero sem repetir. Tentei algo desse tipo mais quando passo 4242 ele não me retorna 4422 e sim 4242 como maior.

```
 static void ComparacoesPossiveis(ref int entrada, out int saida)
        {
            saida = 1;
            for (int i = 1; i <= entrada; i++)
            {
                saida *= i;
            }
        }

        public static void teste(int number)
        {
            if (number >= 10000000)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(-1);
                Console.ReadKey();
                return;
            }

            var array = number.ToString().ToArray();

            int tamanhoArray = array.Length;
            int[] vetor = new int[tamanhoArray];
            int[] temp = new int[tamanhoArray];
            int[] vetTmp = new int[tamanhoArray];

            for (int i = 0; i < tamanhoArray; i++)
            {
                vetor[i] = Convert.ToInt32(array[i].ToString());
            }

            int y, x;
            y = vetor.Length;
            ArrayList combinacoes = new ArrayList();

            ComparacoesPossiveis(ref y, out x);

            while (x > 0)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < y - 1; j++)
                {

                    string numero = "";

                    vetTmp[j] = vetor[j];
                    vetor[j] = vetor[j + 1];
                    vetor[j + 1] = vetTmp[j];


                    for (int i = 0; i < vetor.Length; i++)
                        numero += vetor[i].ToString();

                    combinacoes.Add(Convert.ToInt32(numero));
                }
                x -= y;
            }

            combinacoes.Sort();

            Console.WriteLine("O maior numero é " + combinacoes[combinacoes.Count - 1].ToString());
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Já que está usando modernidades e funções prontas que fazem o trabalho pra você, não tem porque complicar tanto:

```
public static int Teste(int number) => number >= 10000000 ? -1 : ToInt32(new string(number.ToString().OrderByDescending(x => x).ToArray()));
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/4eaqhn). E [no **.NET Fiddle**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/9sjFPf). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Linq/Permutation.cs).

Note que eu separei o processamento da apresentação, assim é mais organizado.

Se fosse usar o código original teria que consertar o erro, mas o erro ocorreu porque o código era complicado demais. Conforme fosse simplificando seria fácil achar o erro, ou a simplificação já eliminaria o erro.

Destaco que aquele código tinha varias inconsistências e usava um padrão não idiomático para C#. Seria fácil eliminar o `ref` e principalmente `out` na função auxiliar.

Não precisaria criar uma lista para gerar o maior número, mas se precisasse, que fosse um [`List<char>`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397&view=net-5.0) e não um `ArrayList` que não deveria mais ser usado em qualquer código.

Tem variáveis demais no código, duplicando o dado de uma variável para outra sem necessidade alguma, laços sem sentido.

Se fosse usar um algoritmo manual, eu começaria fazer um do zero de forma mais simples.

Comment: Inteligente! Quando se encontra a pergunta certa para o problema que queremos encontrar a solução, normalmente, se torna simples. O problema, se não pensarmos em permutações torna-se mais fácil de resolver.

Comment: Então, não sei. Pode ser que realmente ele queria fazer as permutações. Mas não tem nenhum motivo natural complicar. Poderia ter por artificialismo. Aí a pergunta deveria constar o que não pode usar, e o que deve fazer obrigatoriamente. Como não tem e o código apresentado já usava coisas prontas, eu foi nessa onda. Se tivesse que fazer as permutações por força de definição, ainda daria para simplificar o código iniciado. O quanto eu não sei, porque não tem parâmetro do que pode usar ou não. Por exemplo, pode usar unção de conversão (*string* -> int -> *string*) ou tem que fazer na mão? `Sort`?

Comment: Sim, não sabemos qual era o propósito do exercício, o mais certo seria ter de calcular as permutações possíveis e depois encontrar aquela que representa o número maior. Não sabendo isso, a sua resposta resolve de forma inteligente o problema. (Entenda que estou a elogiar  e não a criticar)

Comment: Eu acho que não precisa calcular nada intermediário, se está pedindo o resultado. Como se chega no maior número é detalhe. A não ser que a definição imponha alguma coisa. Não se preocupe, eu sei que não é crítica. Mesmo que fosse, nenhum problema. Não ache que qualquer comentário seja algum problema. É só informação complementar.